# "Sites like Facebook do/does use ..."

Tags: single-word-requests

When I am talking about plural ("Sites"), should I use does or do?
In case I'm talking in plural, I should use "do". But "like Facebook", is singular. So which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you would use the plural "do." The prepositional phrase "like Facebook" modifies the plural noun "sites," and is not itself the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Although really, you'd probably drop "do" altogether and say "Sites like Facebook use..." You'd still use the plural here, to agree with the plural subject.

Comment: Not always. If the main subject is say, a specific secure privacy technology, then sites like Facebook 'do' use this technology. Although realistically the Facebook site probably doesn't use it.

Comment: osknows, that still is a plural verb phrase. "many sites do use that technology". The singular would be "one site does use that technology"

Comment: @teylyn I agree it's plural. I was indicating more about dropping the use of 'do'